# What are the differences between Scalar query and Entity query?

Tags: hibernate

I am learning Hibernate Native SQL from this link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

Through the tutorial I still don't know what is the difference between Scalar query and Entity query.

In the example, they both return a list. So I think any Scalar query can be written as Entity query and vice versa. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

**Scalar Query : -** Just like an plain JDBC where you will write a SQL query and you will get result based on how many columns data you want

```
Ex : - Select fname,lname,gender from person where fname="ex1";
```

Person.java (Entity class)

```
personObj.setFname(fname);
personObj.setLname(lname);
personObj.setGender(gender);
```

in the above query you got three values fname, lname, gender now you to handle these three values individually and if your have created any POJO class for person than you will set these values one by one. So its like you will get raw values which you need handle or parse as per your need,

**Entity queries : -** With the help of entity query you do not need to handle the individual column return by the SQL it will directly parse into your Entitiy class (pojo class). Previously in scalar query you have to use getter and setter for assigning the values in entity but in entity queries the results will automatically get parse into the Entity class (POJO class)

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Employee.class);
```

no need to parse or user getter setter of Employee class Employee will automatically have the values from the database.